# Type hints for dataclass defined inside a class with generic types

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I know that the title is very confusing, so let me take the Binary Search Tree as an example:

#### Using ordinary class definition

```python
# This code passed mypy test
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
class BST(Generic[T]):
    class Node:        
        def __init__(
            self,
            val: T,
            left: 'BST.Node',
            right: 'BST.Node'
        ) -> None:
            self.val = val
            self.left = left
            self.right = right
```

The above code passed `mypy` test.

#### Using `dataclass`

However, when I tried to use `dataclass` to simplify the definition of `Node`, the code failed in mypy test.

```python
# This code failed to pass mypy test
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
class BST(Generic[T]):
    @dataclass
    class Node:
        val: T
        left: 'BST.Node'
        right: 'BST.Node'
```

`mypy` gave me this error message: (`test_typing.py:8` is the line `val: T`)

```
test_typing.py:8: error: Type variable "test_typing.T" is unbound
test_typing.py:8: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[T]" or "Protocol[T]" base class to bind "T" inside a class)
test_typing.py:8: note: (Hint: Use "T" in function signature to bind "T" inside a function)
```

#### Pinpoint the problem

```python
# This code passed mypy test, suggest the problem is the reference to `T` in the dataclass definition
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
class BST(Generic[T]):
    @dataclass
    class Node:
        val: int # chose `int` just for testing
        left: 'BST.Node'
        right: 'BST.Node'
```

The above code agained passed the test, so I think the problem is the reference to `T` in the dataclass definition. Does anyone know how to future fix this to meet my original goal?

Comment: Is there any reason why Node is defined inside BST?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Just want to make `Node` kind of private. I think this is common in Java.

Comment: Just be aware that it won’t be private at all. It will just have a slightly longer global name and suffer from class scoping rules (one of which you have just discovered).

Comment: Yeah, I know python doesn't support real privatization. Thanks for reminding though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with what is written in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id21) about scoping rules for type variables:

> A generic class nested in another generic class **cannot use same type variables**. The scope of the type variables of the **outer class doesn't cover the inner one**:
>
> ```
> T = TypeVar('T')
> S = TypeVar('S')
>
> class Outer(Generic[T]):
>    class Bad(Iterable[T]):       # Error
>        ...
>    class AlsoBad:
>        x = None  # type: List[T] # Also an error
>
>    class Inner(Iterable[S]):     # OK
>        ...
>    attr = None  # type: Inner[T] # Also OK
> ```

This is why your example with nested decorated class does not work.

Now let's answer the question why the example works with `__init__` function that takes `TypeVar` variable.

This is because the method `__init__` is treated by mypy as a generic method with an independent `TypeVar` variable. For example `reveal_type(BST[int].Node.__init__)` shows `Revealed type is 'def [T, T] (self: main.BST.Node, val: T'-1, left: main.BST.Node, right: main.BST.Node)'`. i.e. `T` is not bound to `int` here.

Answer (score 4):

Nested classes cannot implicitly use a `TypeVar` from their containing classes: The nested class must be `Generic` with an unbound `TypeVar`.

```py
BT = TypeVar('BT')
NT = TypeVar('NT')

class BST(Generic[BT]):
    root: 'BST.Node[BT]'  # root note is of same type as search tree

    @dataclass
    class Node(Generic[NT]):  # generic node may be of any type
        val: NT
        left: 'BST.Node[NT]'
        right: 'BST.Node[NT]'
```

This makes the nested class well-defined when referred to outside of its containing class. The underlying issue is that the nested class exists separately of the outer specialistaion – inference only knows `BST.Node` or `BST.Node[T]`, not `BST[T].Node`.

---

Since nesting does not provide any functional advantages, it is usually simpler to define separate classes reusing the same `TypeVar`

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

class BST(Generic[T]):
    root: 'Node[T]'

@dataclass
class Node(Generic[T]):
    val: T
    left: 'Node[T]'
    right: 'Node[T]'
```